# Insert into MySQL table, overwrite on duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I need MySQL to only `INSERT` a value if the `order_id` does not exist in the database, so that duplicate rows are not inserted. If the `order_id` is found, I need the existing data fields to be overwritten. `order_id` should be unique in all instances.

What's the best way to achieve this?

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO carts VALUES(:order_id, :items, :shipping,   :price)");
$params = array(
  ':order_id' => $_SESSION['order_id'],
  ':items'    => Array(),
  ':shipping' => '0',
  ':price'    => '0'
);
if($statement->execute($params)) {
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ?

Comment: you want 'replace into'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First ensure that your table has `order_id` as a primary/unique key. 
If you want the existing fields to be overwritten the query should be like below.

```
INSERT INTO carts VALUES(:order_id, :items, :shipping, :price) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE items = values(items), shipping = values(shipping);
```

The above query will just overwrite the values of the other columns.

Comment: Interesting, I get the error 'This table does not contain a unique column.' in phpmyadmin; not sure how to achieve that, but I'll do some research. Thanks very much! This looks promising.

Comment: you need to alter your table and add a primary/unique key on order_id column.

Comment: This is perfect, I did just that and it's working. Thanks very much!